# Function expected ) on tic tac toe game

Tags: function, tic-tac-toe, qbasic

iam making a tic tac toe on QBasic but I have a problem with a function and i don't know fix it
The error is "Expected ) on current line" but i don't know where put )

```
FUNCTION HayGanador() as string  'the error is on this line
    FOR i = 1 TO 3
        IF Tablero(i, 1) <> "" AND Tablero(i, 1) = Tablero(i, 2) AND Tablero(i, 1) = Tablero(i, 3) THEN
            HayGanador = -1
            EXIT FUNCTION
        END IF

        IF Tablero(1, i) <> "" AND Tablero(1, i) = Tablero(2, i) AND Tablero(1, i) = Tablero(3, i) THEN
            HayGanador = -1
            EXIT FUNCTION
        END IF
    NEXT i

    IF Tablero(1, 1) <> "" AND Tablero(1, 1) = Tablero(2, 2) AND Tablero(1, 1) = Tablero(3, 3) THEN
        HayGanador = -1
        EXIT FUNCTION
    END IF
    IF Tablero(1, 3) <> "" AND Tablero(1, 3) = Tablero(2, 2) AND Tablero(1, 3) = Tablero(3, 1) THEN
        HayGanador = -1
        EXIT FUNCTION
    END IF
    HayGanador = 0
END FUNCTION
```

I was trying to enter a function that identifies the winner of the tic tac toe game but I don't know how to make this function a string

Comment: see: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QBasic/Subroutines_and_Functions#Declaring_a_function "Functions are declared in the same way as variables - it returns the variable type it's defined to return, in the same way variables are defined to contain their specified type. By default, it is a number, but appending a dollar sign indicates that it is returning a string."

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is correct syntax:

```
   FUNCTION HayGanador$()
FOR i = 1 TO 3
    IF Tablero(i, 1) <> "" AND Tablero(i, 1) = Tablero(i, 2) AND Tablero(i, 1) = Tablero(i, 3) THEN
        HayGanador = -1
        EXIT FUNCTION
    END IF
...
```

Your syntax which is throwing error is syntax possible in Visual Basic, but not in QBasic. In QB you can only define function return type using shorthands !, #, %, &, $ for single, double, integer, long and string respectively

Comment: Would you mind explaining your answer a little bit?